# Как установить gem json версии 1.7.7?

Tags: gems, windows, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Не могу установить json 1.7.7 в Rails 3.2.12. Использую Windows, в командной строке следующая ошибка:

```
d:\projects\time-72>gem install json -v '1.7.7'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
"make" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.
7 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/ge
nerator/gem_make.out
```

Может кто сталкивался, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дело в том, что некоторые гемы написаны частично на Си. Соотвественно нужно иметь сишный компилятор, а также пачку вспомогательных тулз и библиотек для установки таких гемов. На линуксе таких проблем нет, там всё встроено.

Если ставили через [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/), то нужно дополнительно установить [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/).

Если ставили как-то иначе, то там тоже должны быть какие-нибудь опции. В худшем случае придётся ставить MinGW или Cygwin, и ещё какие-нибудь зависимости.

Легче просто снести старый руби и поставить через RubyInstaller.

Comment: Спасибо, я изначально делал все по инструкции на офф. сайте. Потом случайно удалил инсталляцию DevKit, после чего предположительно и возникла эта ошибка. Решил проблему переустановкой все этого добра заново, вместе с руби и рельсами. Насчет сишного компилятора - это да, не каждый гем поставишь на винду)